# Spark SQL not able to read HDFS subfolders recursively of a hive table (Spark - 2.4.6)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

We are trying to read a hive table using Spark-SQL, but it is not displaying any record (giving 0 records in output). On checking we found that the HDFS files of the table are stored in multiple subdirectories like this -

```
hive> [hadoop@ip-10-37-195-106 CDPJobs]$ hdfs dfs -ls /its/cdp/refn/cot_tbl_cnt_hive/     
Found 18 items     
drwxrwxr-x+ - hadoop hadoop 0 2021-12-19 20:17 /its/cdp/refn/cot_tbl_cnt_hive/1     
drwxrwxr-x+ - hadoop hadoop 0 2021-12-19 20:17 /its/cdp/refn/cot_tbl_cnt_hive/10     
drwxrwxr-x+ - hadoop hadoop 0 2021-12-19 20:17 /its/cdp/refn/cot_tbl_cnt_hive/11     
drwxrwxr-x+ - hadoop hadoop 0 2021-12-19 20:17 /its/cdp/refn/cot_tbl_cnt_hive/12     
drwxrwxr-x+ - hadoop hadoop 0 2021-12-19 20:17 /its/cdp/refn/cot_tbl_cnt_hive/13     
drwxrwxr-x+ - hadoop hadoop 0 2021-12-19 20:17 /its/cdp/refn/cot_tbl_cnt_hive/14     
drwxrwxr-x+ - hadoop hadoop 0 2021-12-19 20:17 /its/cdp/refn/cot_tbl_cnt_hive/15
```

We tried setting below properties in spark-defaults.conf file, but still the issue persists.

```
set spark.hadoop.hive.supports.subdirectories = true;    
set spark.hadoop.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories = true;     
set spark.hadoop.hive.input.dir.recursive=true;     
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive=true;          
set recursiveFileLookup=true;            
set spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;         
set spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive=true;
```

Does someone know any solution to this? We are using Spark version 2.4.6.

**Update (Resolution found) -**

I have changed this property as false and now spark is able to read data from subdirectories.

set spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false;

Answer (score 0):

```
sparkSession = (SparkSession
                    .builder
                    .appName('USS - Unified Scheme of Sells')
                    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://probighhwm001:9083", conf=SparkConf())
                    .config("hive.input.dir.recursive", "true")
                    .config("hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories", "true")
                    .config("hive.supports.subdirectories", "true")
                    .config("mapred.input.dir.recursive", "true")
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate()
                    )
```

Comment: I already tried with these properties too in spark, but it's not working...